# Insert an object in lowdb Node.js DB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database

Using [typicode/lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) in Node.JS. With the following JSON database:

```
{
  "name": "Louie Littel",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "item"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't insert a new object with the query:

```
db.get('db').filter({ name: "Louie Littel" }).pick('items').push({ name: "item2" }).value();
```

I can, however insert a new object in the root level, for example:

```
db.get('db').push({ name: "item2" }).value();
```

But I have to add the new object inside the "items" property. **How can I add a new object to the "items" property of my object?**

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am experiencing the same issue :)

Comment: Hello @Pirozek, I don't remember what the outcome was. But I think it was because lowdb does not write contents to the file right after pushing the value. It keeps it in memory, try inserting more objects or retrieving the object and you may see the actual data. Let me know the results to write an answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: Well my problem was with inserting data and I forgot to call `.value()` :) So its not really related to your issue, it just looks similar